# Echo variable inside Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I would like to be able to define a URL inside my config file and echo the url inside array:

```
$options = array( 'results_per_page' => 30,
                  'url' => 'http://localhost/page.php?page=*VAR*',
                  'db_handle' => $dbh
                );
```

In this case let's say I would like to define a variable:

`$url = 'http://localhost/';`

or

```
define( "SERVER_PATH", "http://localhost/" );
```

and being able to echo it inside the `'url' => "$url" page.php?page=*VAR*'`

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: why do you want to echo it inside an array? practically it's not possible.

Comment: because I have this line in different php files and want to change the url in one place instead of each of them.

Comment: You are probably looking for [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Create a temp `$tmpUrl  = $url` then use that `'url' => "$tmpUrl" . "page.php?page=*VAR*'"` I don't know I fully understand the issue but it seems like you do not want to overwrite something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way:

Using variable:

```
$options = array( 'results_per_page' => 30,
                  'url' => $url . 'page.php?page=*VAR*',
                  'db_handle' => $dbh
                );
```

Using constant:

```
$options = array( 'results_per_page' => 30,
                  'url' => SERVER_PATH . 'page.php?page=*VAR*',
                  'db_handle' => $dbh
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also append the variable to the end of the array value by using the concatenation operator

```
$option['url'] = $option ['url'] . $var;
```

Or in less words

```
$option['url'] .= $var;
```